# How to allow new users as default access Remote Desktop

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2019

I have Windows Server 2019 in a company and I want to allow each new user would be able to login remotely by default.

I have added `DefaultAccount` user to `Remote Desktop Users` group, rebooted the server and created a new user, but this new user does not have RDP access.

Is there a way to reach this so that I don't need to add each user to `Remote Desktop Users` group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server in question, open control panel and go into “System and Security” then click “Allow remote access”. At the bottom click select users and click add. Then search for “Everyone” and add that